# Ubuntu Clean Install on new HD for Dell Latitude E6420

Tags: 14.04, dell

I tired to clean install Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Latitude E6420, using bootable USB made using universal USB installer.

Installation went OK with no errors but when it rebooted it gives No Boot Device Detected. I configured the BIOS to be UEFI and the SATA controller to be AHCI. Then tired the Legacy instead of UEFI and AHCI remains same but with no luck and got same error.

Can you please help?

---

Actually I wasn't given any options when I created my USB. And No, I didn't have it installed. I brought a new HD and tried to install several time but the same errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installaton of ubuntu 14.04 on dell precision t7810 fails: No boot device found](http://askubuntu.com/questions/657477/installaton-of-ubuntu-14-04-on-dell-precision-t7810-fails-no-boot-device-found)

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. Then you have to set UEFI/BIOS to boot in that same boot mode. You actually have three modes: UEFI with Secure boot, UEFI, and BIOS. Install and boot must match. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and while dual boot shows install screens: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 1):

Did you read all [these articles?](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=no+boot+device)

There are really a lot of possible causes for this behavior. Try to do a complete new install of ubuntu while the **BIOS is in legacy mode**. Setup the SATA controller as AHCI is fine and should left untouched.  Ensure that the harddisk has an **MBR partition table**! Install the grub loader as a MBR (i.e. /dev/sda) and not as an bootrecord (i.e. /dev/sda1).

To ensure that the disk has a MBR parition table you may boot the ubuntu life system and create a new empty partition table on your harddisk with the fdisk or gparted programs.

---

You may start an ubuntu live system and open a terminal. Gain root access in the terminal shell by typing

```
sudo -i
```

Than try to find out the device name of your hard disk, have a look at the output of

```
ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/
```

There should be a line ending up in /dev/sda or /dev/sdb where the left part thereon meets your diskname.

Supposed it is `/dev/sda`, than you start fdisk:

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

In fdisk you can get an overview about available commands by typing <kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>.

Create a new MBR partition table with <kbd>o</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> and write it to the disk and leave the fdisk program with <kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>.

Thereafter reboot the system and try again an installation of ubuntu on the disk.

Comment: I installed using Legacy and AHCI but no boot device error came up too. Can you please explain further the MBR route? I am not an expert in Ubuntu

Comment: are you able to start a ubuntu live system from a usb stick and start a shell?

Comment: If you mean trying Ubuntu and starting the terminal then yes.

Comment: I edited the post to give you some hints

Comment: Hello I tried this and it gave an error that this is not GPT but I clicked yes and wen smooth but ended up with same error. I even tried again with Ubuntu 12.04 with UEFI and AHCI and got same error. I don't know why this is happening this should be a straight forward